# Getting "/usr/bin/python: No module named" whenever I run the Docker container

Tags: docker, flask, deployment, dockerfile, python-3.6

I have a flask API alongside with another class for Machine learning prediction that I need to dockerize so I have a Dockerfile as shown below. I run the container using

`sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 test`

However every-time I run it, it crashes.

I can see that the status of it "Exited (1)" whenever I run
`docker ps --all`

When I do `docker logs containerIDHere` I get the reason of the crash as below

/usr/local/bin/python: No module named

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

COPY Network /app

COPY Train /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "-m" ,"Network.Api"]
```

Comment: You cant copy two directories into one location inside the container

Comment: Remove the trailing space from `"-m "`

Comment: Thanks @AlexSmith this has helped me. I now do "COPY . /app" instead of "COPY Network /app" and "COPY Train /app" and it works!!

Comment: Thanks @DaveW.Smith, I have also removed the trailing space from "-m"